# Spark: OneHot encoder and storing Pipeline (feature dimension issue)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

We have a pipeline (2.0.1) consisting of multiple feature transformation stages.

Some of these stages are OneHot encoders. Idea: classify an integer-based category into n independent features.

When training the pipeline model and using it to predict all works fine. However, storing the trained pipeline model and reloading it causes issues:

The stored 'trained' OneHot encoder does not keep track of how many categories there are. Loading it now causes issues: When the loaded model is used to predict, it redetermines how many categories there are, causing the training feature space and prediction feature space to be of a different size (dimension). See the example code below as run in a Zeppelin notebook:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel


// Specifying two test samples, one with class 5 and one with class 3. This is OneHot encoded into 5 boolean features (sparse vector)
// Adding a 'filler' column because createDataFrame doesnt like single-column sequences and this is the easiest way to demo it ;)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((5, 1), (3, 1))).toDF("class", "filler")

val enc = new OneHotEncoder()
  .setInputCol("class")
  .setOutputCol("class_one_hot")

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(enc))

val model = pipeline.fit(df)
model.transform(df).show()

/*
+-----+------+-------------+
|class|filler|class_one_hot|
+-----+------+-------------+
|    5|     1|(5,[],[])    |
|    3|     1|(5,[3],[1.0])|
+-----+------+-------------+

Note: Vector of size 5
*/

model.write.overwrite().save("s3a://one-hot")

val loadedModel = PipelineModel.load("s3a://one-hot")

val df2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((3, 1))).toDF("class", "output") // When using the trained model our input consists of one row (prediction engine style). The provided category for the prediction feature set is category 3
loadedModel.transform(df2).show()

/*
+-----+------+-------------+
|class|output|class_one_hot|
+-----+------+-------------+
|    3|     1|(3,[],[])    |
+-----+------+-------------+

Note: Incompatible vector of size 3
*/
```

I'd prefer to not make my own OneHot encoder that DOES support this serialization, are there any alternatives that I can use out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.3**

Spark 2.3 introduces [`OneHotEncoderEstimator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoderEstimator) (to be renamed as `OneHotEncoder` in Spark 3.0) which can be used directly, and supports multiple input columns.

**Spark < 2.3**

You don't use `OneHotEncoder` as it is intended to be used. `OneHotEncoder` is a `Transofrmer` not an `Estimator`. It doesn't store any information about the levels but depends on the `Column` metadata to determine output dimensions. If metadata is missing, like in your case, it uses fallback strategy and assumes there is `max(input_column)` levels. Serialization is irrelevant here.

Typical usage involves `Transformers` in the upstream `Pipeline`, which set metadata for you. One common example is `StringIndexer`.

It is still possible to set metadata manually, but it is more involved:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.NominalAttribute

val meta = NominalAttribute.defaultAttr
  .withName("class")
  .withValues("0", (1 to 5).map(_.toString): _*)
  .toMetadata

loadedModel.transform(df2.select($"class".as("class", meta), $"output"))
```

Similarly in Python (needs Spark >= 2.2):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

meta = {"ml_attr": {
    "vals": [str(x) for x in range(6)],   # Provide a set of levels
    "type": "nominal", 
    "name": "class"}}

loaded.transform(
    df.withColumn("class", col("class").alias("class", metadata=meta))
)
```

Metadata can be also attached using a number of different methods: [How to change column metadata in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44273080).