# How to change column metadata in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, metadata, apache-spark-ml

How can I update column metadata in PySpark?
I have metadata values corresponding to nominal encoding of categorical (string) features and I would like to decode them back in automated way. Writing the metadata in PySpark API is not directly available unless you recreate the schema. Is it possible to edit metadata in PySpark on the go without converting dataset to RDD and converting it back, provided complete schema description (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473380/how-can-i-declare-a-column-as-a-categorical-feature-in-a-dataframe-for-use-in-ml))?

Example listing:

```py
# Create DF
df.show()

# +---+-------------+
# | id|     features|
# +---+-------------+
# |  0|[1.0,1.0,4.0]|
# |  1|[2.0,2.0,4.0]|
# +---+-------------+
# - That one has all the necessary metadata about what is encoded in feature column

# Slice one feature out
df = VectorSlicer(inputCol='features', outputCol='categoryIndex', indices=[1]).transform(df)
df = df.drop('features')
# +---+-------------+
# | id|categoryIndex|
# +---+-------------+
# |  0|        [1.0]|
# |  1|        [2.0]|
# +---+-------------+
# categoryIndex now carries metadata about singular array with encoding

# Get rid of the singular array
udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: float(x[0]), returnType=DoubleType())
df2 = df.select(*[udf(column).alias(column) if column == 'categoryIndex' else column for column in df.columns])
# +---+-------------+
# | id|categoryIndex|
# +---+-------------+
# |  0|          1.0|
# |  1|          2.0|
# +---+-------------+
# - Metadata is lost for that one


# Write metadata
extract = {...}
df2.schema.fields[1].metadata = extract(df.schema.fields[1].metadata)
# metadata is readable from df2.schema.fields[1].metadata but is not affective. 
# Saving and restoring df from parque destroys the change
# Decode categorical
df = IndexToString(inputCol="categoryIndex", outputCol="category").transform(df)
# ERROR. Was supposed to decode the categorical values
```

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473380/how-can-i-declare-a-column-as-a-categorical-feature-in-a-dataframe-for-use-in-ml) provides an insight about how to work with VectorAssembler, VectorIndexer and how to add metadata by constructing a complete schema using StructType but yet does not answer my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In both cases losing metadata is expected:

- When you call Python `udf` there is no relationship between input `Column` and its metadata, and output `Column`. `UserDefinedFunction` (both in Python and Scala) are black boxes for the Spark engine.
- Assigning data directly to the Python schema object:

  ```
  df2.schema.fields[1].metadata = extract(df.schema.fields[1].metadata)
  ```

  **is not a valid approach** at all. Spark `DataFrame` is a thing wrapper around JVM object. Any changes in the Python wrappers, are completely opaque for JVM backend, and won't be propagated at all:

  ```py
  import json 

  df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo")], ("k", "v"))
  df.schema[-1].metadata = {"foo": "bar"}

  json.loads(df._jdf.schema().json())

  ## {'fields': [{'metadata': {}, 'name': 'k', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'long'},
  ##   {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'v', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'}],
  ## 'type': 'struct'}
  ```

  or even preserved in Python:

  ```py
  df.select("*").schema[-1].metadata
  ## {}
  ```

With **Spark < 2.2** you can use a small wrapper (taken from [Spark Gotchas](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/06_data_preparation.md#python), maintained by me and [@eliasah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah)):

```py
def withMeta(self, alias, meta):
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    jmeta = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata
    return Column(getattr(self._jc, "as")(alias, jmeta.fromJson(json.dumps(meta))))

df.withColumn("foo", withMeta(col("foo"), "", {...}))
```

With **Spark >= 2.2** you can use `Column.alias`:

```py
df.withColumn("foo", col("foo").alias("", metadata={...}))
```

Comment: In spark 2.2 instead of `df.withColumn("foo", col("foo").alias("", metadata={...}))` it should be `df.withColumn("foo", col("foo").as("", metadata={...}))` ?

Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#as-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata-

Comment: @Sigrist These are Java docs. Using `as` is a keyword in Python.

Answer (score 2):

**Spark 3.3+**

```py
df.withMetadata("col_name", {...})
```

Example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2)], ["c1", "c2"])
df = df.withMetadata("c2", {"description": "my_meta"})

print(df.schema["c2"].metadata)
# {'description': 'my_meta'}
```