# Specify pyspark dataframe schema with string longer than 256

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I'm reading a source that got descriptions longer then 256 chars. I want to write them to Redshift.

According to: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#configuring-the-maximum-size-of-string-columns it is only possible in Scala.

According to this: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/137#issuecomment-165904691
it should be a workaround to specify the schema when creating the dataframe. I'm not able to get it to work.

How can I specify the schema with varchar(max)?

```python
df = ...from source

schema = StructType([
    StructField('field1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('description', StringType(), True)
])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redshift `maxlength` annotations are passed in format

```
{"maxlength":2048}
```

so this is the structure you should pass to `StructField` constructor:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType

StructField("description", StringType(), metadata={"maxlength":2048})
```

or alias method:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

col("description").alias("description", metadata={"maxlength":2048})
```

If you use PySpark 2.2 or earlier please check  [How to change column metadata in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273080/how-to-change-column-metadata-in-pyspark) for workaround.

Comment: Setting this as the correct answer, even tho I did not get it to work yet, it answers my question. It should also work in python now as well, according to https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-redshift.html#additional-configuration-options (Databricks have recently closed-sourced the spark-redshift project)